# How can a small volume of gas balance the pressure exerted by the whole atmosphere?

Tags: pressure

Consider a balloon filled with Helium or even air for that matter. The membrane of the balloon is in equilibrium because the atmospheric pressure on it exerted by the atmosphere, the elastic force by the membrane and the outward pressure by the helium gas inside exactly balance.

My question is,how can such a small volume of gas inside the balloon balance the pressure exerted by the huge atmosphere? I think this has to do something with the fact that the pressure exerted by the atmosphere is due to its weight whereas the pressure exerted by the gas in the balloon is just due to its intrinsic tendency to expand.

Is this really the reason? If so, how can such a small amount of helium counteract the whole weight of the atmosphere? And are these two 'types' of pressures really different at the molecular level? Why?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the atmosphere exerts a force in all directions. If you think of a thin layer of atmosphere surrounding the balloon, it also pushes against the atmosphere.

Of course the air in the balloon is also part of the atmosphere pushing outwards. You could just as easily have put a box on the table, and a lid on top. The air inside the box pushes from below and balances the pressure from above.

If you take the air out of the container (eg. condensing steam in a thin metal can), as you have probably seen, the atmosphere crushes it without problem. See "[55 gallon steel drum can crush](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JsoE4F2Pb20)"

Comment: But that still doesn't answer my question. I'm aware that the air in the balloon is a part of the atmosphere, but how can such a volume it exert the atmospheric pressure all by itself?

Comment: Gas pressure derives from the motion of molecules. Those in the balloon are no different form those in the surrounding atmosphere. The skin of the balloon is just a arbitrary surround, no different to soap bubble, in which the pressure on each side of the film is the same.

Comment: The forces balance. Pressure is force per unit area. The whole atmosphere is not pressing on the balloon. Just the part in contact with the balloon. And that is the same size as the balloon that presses back.

Comment: @gerard, the box example is absolutely relevant to your question.  Ask yourself, "why, when I close an empty box, is the box not immediately crushed by the immense weight of the atmosphere?"  The answer is, because before I closed the lid, the air in the box was part _of_ the atmosphere.  It was already compressed to the same pressure as the air outside the box.  The pressure inside the box pushing out is exactly the same as the pressure outside pushing in.  That means, no _net_ pressure on the walls of the box.

Comment: Only difference between the balloon and the box is that, in order to get the air/helium/whatever into the balloon, it has to be pumped up to an even _higher_ pressure in order to inflate the elastic balloon.

Comment: @Solomon If a box has vacuum inside it, by your explanation, it will be crushed. If you think pure vacuum is not possible consider gradually taking air out of the box. Compared to when box has same amount of air as equal volume of atmosphere outside, when air is removed from the box, even slightly, the inner pressure must decrease, right? The now less number of molecules dont increase their pressure. If you think they do then where do that energy come from? There must now, as air is removed, net force on the box. The box therefore should collapse because as per you its air that do the balance.

Comment: @Solomon (contd.) Its because of this I think your explanation is wrong. Box dont collapse because its walls and roof take the pressure. Consider putting a box made of light material, say thin plastic, in water. If the box is not filled with water it will collapse due to vibration of water molecules outside the box. Your box is not _filled_ with air because more air can be added in it.

Comment: @Atif, Re, "Box don't collapse..." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0TQxYemrgg

Comment: @Solomon The setup of the experiment cause air inside to move inwards. This is why the box implodes. It has nothing to do with air outside. You are confused because you think thin film of air thats just touching the air outside the box is strong enough to collapse the box, otherwise its easy to convince you that doing same experiment by putting the box inside a shipping container where there is little air outside will have the same result.

Comment: @Solomon Consider how thin the as per you effective air outside the box is. Just the molecules that touch the box, right? Whats their mass? How much momentum can they have at that temperature? You can calculate that. Its negligible. Consider quickly moving the box and put your hand there. Feel anything? Nothing. Consider putting a small punching machine that has steel balls that continuously punch the box. The box will not collapse. Its walls can endure that. Are you saying one-molecule thick layer of air at normal pressure has more force than that?

Comment: @Atif, Re, "The setup...cause air inside to move inward." You can do the experiment yourself. If you don't want to procure a giant steel chemical drum, you can use a [steel jug with a tight-fitting lid](https://www.uline.com/Product/Detail/S-22157/Hazardous-Materials-Packaging/Metal-F-Style-Can-with-Cap-1-Gallon). Put a small amount of water in the container. Heat the container on a flame or on a stove-top until the water boils. Let it boil long enough for the steam to _drive out all of the air._ Then, remove the heat and quickly seal the container.\* Stand back, wait and watch.

Comment: \* Please be sure to protect your hands. Live steam can give you serious burns, and it can happen in less time than it takes for you to react to the pain.

Comment: @Solomon What would repeating the experiment prove? As long as air is hot enough and the thickness of jug is small enough the jug will collapse. You can get the same result (collapse of jug) by pouring hot water at outside wall of jug. It will still collapse / bend showing air pressure outside has nothing to do with it. Try this experiment slowly. As per you and the video it should give same result. In reality, it wouldnt. Your experiment work only if there is a sudden sucking in. Its just shock waves. Fire little rockets inside the jug from inner wall to center of jug, same result.

Answer (score 0):

All pressure$^1$ is due to a material wanting to expand.

Pressure is defined as a force over an area. In the case of a gas, the force isn't a constant but comes from the time and area average of many collisions with your measuring surface. You can increase the average force by either increasing the number of particles colliding each second by increasing the density$^2$, or you can increase how hard each particle hits by increasing their velocities by increasing the temperature. You can see this from a version of the ideal gas law:

$$P=\rho\,R^*\,T$$

Where $P$ is pressure, $\rho$ is the density, $T$ is the temperature (in absolute units)$^3$, and $R^*$ is the specific gas constant.

In the case of a balloon the temperature should be roughly equal on each side of the balloon and isn't much in our control$^4$. Thus to fill a balloon we must cram more and more molecules into the balloon so the density is high enough to balance the atmospheric pressure.

So then one may wonder how people can blow up a balloon with their lungs, if the weight of the atmosphere is creating the pressure on the outside of the balloon. The answer is that the atmosphere helps us out by compressing the outside of our lungs helping us push the air into the balloon.

$^1$ Dynamic pressure also includes pressure due to a change in velocity, like a wave pushing someone over. However, static pressures are all about the material trying to return to its most relaxed state. Sometimes, in the case of liquids and solids this can mean there's a negative pressure if the liquid or solid is being stretched.

$^2$ The number of collisions is also increased by increasing the velocity of each collision. This means that the velocity gets to contribute twice. Fortunately temperature is dependent on the average square velocity, so the pressure just depends linearly on temperature.

$^3$ The temperature must be in absolute units because the pressure would only be zero at absolute zero, not say the freezing point of water (Celsius), or a saltwater slushy (Fahrenheit).

$^4$ If you place the balloon in the freezer, its temperature will decrease, but the atmospheric pressure will still be pushing on the outside so the balloon will collapse until the pressure is balanced by the increased density.